# How to Change Image Source using Jquery using effects and looping?

Tags: jquery

I want change the image source from `image1.png` to `image2.png` (with `fade`) and loop.
I have this code below  but this isn't looping to image1.png.

**My code**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.class')
             .attr('src','image2.png')
             .stop(true,true).hide()
             .fadeIn('slow');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var source = jQuery('.class').attr('src') == 'image2.png' ? 'image1.png' : 'image2.png'
    $('.class').attr('src',source ).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn('slow'); 
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
  var image = $('.class');
  var src = image.attr('src') === 'image1.png' ? 'image2.png' : 'image1.png';
  image.attr('src', src).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn('slow');
}, 1000);
```